# Cargar animaciones de animate.css varias veces

Tags: html, css, animación

Tengo este boton que, cuando carga le seteo "animated flash" como clase para que haga la animacion "flash" de animate.css. El problema que tengo es al ponerle de nuevo la clase al dar click al boton, que no coge la animacion. Alguna forma de solucionar esto?

```js
var elemento = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
elemento[0].setAttribute("class","animated flash")

function handleOnClick(e) {
    console.log("button clicked");
    const button = e.target;
    button.setAttribute("class", "animated flash");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<button onclick="handleOnClick(event)"> myAnimatedButton </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías eliminar la clase y volverla a agregar.

El código sería algo así:

```js
var elemento = document.getElementsByTagName("button")
elemento[0].setAttribute("class","animated flash")

function handleOnClick(e) {
    console.log("button clicked");
    const button = e.target;
    button.classList.remove("flash");
    void button.offsetWidth;
    button.classList.add("flash");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<button onclick="handleOnClick(event)"> myAnimatedButton </button>
```

Comment: No funciona :\. Tambien deberia de haber una forma no tan nuclear, `removeAttribute` borrarria otras clases y estilos aplicados al boton, no?

Comment: Actualicé el código, ahora sí debería de funcionar.

Comment: Pero todavia borraria los demas estilos aplicados al boton, no? y no entiendo por que `void button.offsetWidth;`

Comment: Sí, el código borraría todos las clases y las volvería a agregar. Lo mejor sería eliminar solo la clase que tiene la animación (con jQuery sería muy sencillo). Luego el código que mencionas es un pequeño truco para resetear la animación, hay más info sobre ello aquí: https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: Volví a actualizar el código. Ahora no remueve todos los estilos, sólo la clase `flash`. ;)